# Why is this question full of &shy; entities?

Tags: bug, questions

I came across a strange thing just now. I have a browser extension that creates and downloads an internet shortcut file (.url) of the current page. I used it on the following page, and the extension broke.

[How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/62442)

When I examined the question title (and later the contents of the question), I noticed that there are many unnecessary `&shy;` entities in the post. Here's a screenshot of the post content:

[image]

The extension is using the window/document title as the file name, and these entities are not allowed in a file name.

I checked the edits and saw that the last edit introduced these `&shy;` entities, and I seem to fail to understand the need for them.

So I'm curious. Was this intentional? Or is it the result of some glitch?

Comment: `&shy;` is HTML code for a soft hyphen.  In a text there can be long words which you might want to line break with a hyphen. But you do not want the hyphen to show if the whole word is on the same line, so soft hyphens are inserted.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That answer the *what*, but I'm more interested in the *why*. For example, what's with the frequency? I don't think using it this frequent is normal. Also, it seems to be randomly inserted.

Comment: I think that some software is soft-hyphenating not randomly, but every word which is capable of hyphenation. Do you see hyphenation of words when the situation requires it, e.g. when resizing or zooming the browser?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I did. I didn't think that a software would be used to do the insertion. I just thought doing this manually would be tiring, so one wouldn't be tempted to do so. If it's a software, does that mean that the editor did the editing in some other software and then pasted the text into the question/browser? If so, I guess he gives it his all :)

Comment: Yes, I edited it using a different program. And your software should not be writing out filenames with invisible characters in them. This sounds like a bug.  (BTW, there is no such thing as "a software" in English; you have to say "a program" instead.)

Answer (score 3):

Your extension should be sanitizing whatever it uses for the file name. These are [soft (or shy) hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), which create breaks inside words as needed, and there's no reason they couldn't be in post titles. (Much worse could also be in post titles...) These hyphens are just a typographical nicety like accents on letters or smart quotes. I'm sure the edit was intentional, as I've seen tchrist make similar formatting edits before.

Comment: I'm doing sanitizing for common pitfalls, but this one is new (to me at least). I know about the entity, but didn't think it would be used this much in a text. Especially, thinking that the editor did this (manually) in the edit page. As Michael pointed out in his comment, the editor might have used a software, which would help a lot with the insertion.

Comment: Some web browsers can automatically insert soft hyphens into the words of text that they render from a web site. It requires a list of hyphenation rules for common words (a kind of dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

Observe:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't remember ever using hypens for the line breaks (unless I'm actually writing using pen/paper). Not a fan of breaking words. I usually wrap or justify the lines. Anyway, here's a [recording of my experiment](https://s10.gifyu.com/images/2021-10-29_00-17-31.gif) with the hypens :)